# How can I make radical function in php?

Tags: php, function

I was trying to make function that gives two value. First value was the respite in the radical and the second value is the number that we want to put it in radical.
It's my code:

```
function radical($respite = 2, $num)
{
    $numbers = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $numbers[] = '0.' . "$i";
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $numbers[] = '1.' . "$i";
    }
    // I wanted do these loop until to creat numbers from 0.1 to 100,
    // but i under stand it's silly work and wrong.
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($numbers); $i++) {
        if ($respite == 2) {
            $hesan = $number["$i"] * $number["$i"];
            if ($hesab == $num) {
                return $hesab;
            }
        } elseif ($respite == 3) {
            $hesan = $number["$i"] * $number["$i"] * $number["$i"];
            if ($hesab == $num) {
                return $hesab;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create numbers from 0.1 to 100. and I wanted write if `$number[$i] * $number[$i] =  $num` return the $number, but I saw it's silly work and wrong my means create numbers from 0.1 to 100 by this way.

For `radical(2, 9)` the output should be 4, because 3 * 3 = 9.
If the first value is 3 `radical(3, 8)` the output should be 2, because 2 * 2 * 2= 8

Can someone make function to do radical with respite ? or improve my code ?

Comment: Can you mention clearly you input and expected output?

Comment: @Sahil  I write this function like this `    radical(2,9)    ` the output should be 4, because 3 * 3 = 9, but if the first value is 3 means `    radical(3,8)    ` the output should be 2, because 2 * 2 * 2= 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for..

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/786816)

```
function radical($respite = 2, $num)
{
    for($x=0;$x<=10;$x+=0.1)
    {
       $numbers[]=$x;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($numbers); $i++)
    {
        if ($respite == 2)
        {
            if ((string)($numbers[$i] * $numbers[$i]) == (string)$num)
            {
                return $numbers[$i];;
            }
        } 
        elseif ($respite == 3)
        {
            if ((string)($numbers[$i] * $numbers[$i]* $numbers[$i]) == (string)$num)
            {
                return $numbers[$i];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r(radical(3, 27));//3
print_r(radical(3, 8));//2
print_r(radical(2, 36));//6
print_r(radical(2, 16));//4
```

Comment: if we don't use **(string)** in the above code , will it be wrong ?

Comment: @MahdiYaghubkhani yes friend  there will be a case when it will wrong,  `$numbers[$i] * $numbers[$i]* $numbers[$i]` will return `float` and `$num` will be `int`, So i type casted both to `string`..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this not as an exercise but for productive use, I suggest this:

```
function radical($num, $respite = 2)
{
    return $num ** (1 / $respite);
}

echo radical(27, 3) . "\n" .
     radical(8,  3) . "\n" .
     radical(36, 2) . "\n" .
     radical(16, 2);
```

Output:

```
3
2
6
4
```

You can see it [here](https://eval.in/788825)

The reason I changed the argument order is that you can't have a required parameter after an optional one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're going for exactly, but I think this cleans up what you have now at least:

```
function radical($num, $respite = 2) {
    $numbers = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
        $numbers[] = $i * 0.1;
    }
    foreach($numbers as $i) {
        if ($respite == 2) {
            $hesab = $i * $i;
            if ($hesab == $num) {
                return $i;
            }
        }
        elseif($respite == 3) {
            $hesab = $i * $i * $i;
            if ($hesab == $num) {
                return $i;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's wrong because it only has numbers of 1.1 and 2.1 , 3.1 .... but it has not 1,2,3 or 3.5.

Comment: I write this function like this ` radical(2,9) ` the output should be 4, because 3 * 3 = 9, but if the first value is 3 means ` radical(3,8) ` the output should be 2, because 2 * 2 * 2= 8.

Comment: As written, `$numbers` includes all values 0.1 through 100 incremented by 0.1. Check out `$numbers[] = $i * 0.1;`.

Comment: Why should `radical(2,9)` return 4? It should be `radical(9,2)`, by the way, because default arguments should be on the right.

Comment: If you want it to return the factor not `$num`, you'd return `$i` not `$hesab`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: excuse me I had to write radical(2,9) return 3 because 3* 3 = 9.

Comment: there is problem in your code again.because if the values are : radical(8,2) it return 0 because there isn't the the answer of √8 in the $numbers.

Comment: `radical(9,2)` returns 3. `radical(8,3)` returns 2. `radical(8,2)` returns 0 because, as you say, the square root is not in `$numbers`. If that's not what you want, please clarify what you want.